# How do I ensure font is installed on SSRS server during deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've recently designed a report which uses a new ttf font file to create a barcode image.
I would like to add this as some form of dependency check to SSRS project so that it checks and if necessary installs the font during deployment. 
Does anyone know if this functionality is built in to VS somewhere or what best practice is for this scenario?

(Note: SQL2012 SP2 db, VS2010 solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but since there were no suggestions and I didn't find any automated way I had to add a manual font installation step to deployment documentation for report.